# how to get zabbix last 20 issue in zabbixAPI?

Tags: json, api, zabbix, monit

Picture as below:
[image: last 20 issues]

I want to build a software to combine the hosts alert from the same group,i used to develop some  batch processing function in PHP to call the zabbix API.So i want to implement that way.

[zabbix 3.0 api](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.2/manual/api/reference/problem/get)
. It seems what i looking for,but on zabbix 2.x,how to get the last 20 issues,it does not have the method "problem.get".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You linked to the 3.2 documentation, which refactored the event an trigger screens into a problem screen (with the necessary API changes).

You want to use the [trigger.get](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/api/reference/trigger/get) method:

```
{
    ...
    "method": "trigger.get",
    "params": {
        "filter": {"value": "1"},
        "sortfield": "lastchange"
        "limit": 20
    }
}
```

This is the basic, you would need to select the proper fields and select* properties to get the rest of the data.

Comment: Thank you very much,that`s what i need